# Cannot Group Header of Slickgrid with Jquery new version

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have slickgrid in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkVc/).

It works with `Jquery version 1.8.3`, but with `jquery version 1.9.1 or 1.10.1`, it doesn't work anymore.

You can change version of jquery in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkVc/) to know more clearly.

My project work with lastest jquery(version `1.10.1` now) and `slickgird`.

Anyone has any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I found that jquery remove something from version `1.9.1`, so I need `jquery-migrate` to make some old function work again.

[Details](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme) for anyone's interested.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkVc/1/)'s working now, after insert `jquery-migrate-1.2.1`.